# Issue with new file wizards in Spring Tool Suite 4.10.0

Tags: html, spring-boot, wizard, sts

When I try to add a new HTML or JSP file to my Spring Boot project, I can't see wizards for these file types. They do not appear in the wizard list. Is it a version related bug or do I have to add these wizards manually?

My current STS version: 4.10.0.RELEASE (Build Id: 202103111225)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that these wizards were removed from Spring Tool Suite 4.10.0.

To add these wizards [Eclipse Enterprise Java and Web Developer Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-enterprise-java-and-web-developer-tools) can be installed from Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

To add these wizard you can go to Help, there you can find out Thymeleaf, and install it, after refreshing STS you can find HTML

STS > HELP > Eclipse Market Place > search the required wizard > Download it